# Why does SQL Server Management Studio sometimes lose my authentication information?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

When I launch SQL Server Management Studio, most of the time it remembers the login & password, but from time to time, I have to retype the password.

Is this something that happens periodically for security, or is it a bug, or is it something that I'm doing?

Comment: Since I don't have the rep to edit your question: It's "lose", not "loose". Can you please fix it for me and all the other pedants? :)

Comment: @Matt Hamilton: This particular misspelling is something that troubles me as well. It seems to affect non-native speakers mainly. It it is spoken as "loose" after all (just like "goose"), while "lose" would have to be pronounced like "hose", naturally. :)

Comment: Corrected the spelling. For information, I am a native speaker, AND a bad typist :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug with SQL Management Studio. [Microsoft seem to be aware](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=222848) of it, but have not fixed it as yet, and many users are experiencing it. Some users have reported success with always running the app as an administrator on Vista or Windows 7.

You can run Managment studio from the command line, and supply your password in this. By creating a shortut to this command it would always remember it, but obviously you would be hardcoding the password in there, not very secure. If you wanted to do thisthe command is:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\
SqlWb.exe" /S yourserver -U youruser -P yourpassword"
```

Comment: I have been experiencing this since I installed SP2 on a SQL Server 2005 instance ;-) Thanks for the solution!